# Sitecore with Docker - Not able to run

Tags: docker

I've cloned the repository https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-images and was able to build the images. But I haven't managed to run the images. 
Please see a screen shot with the list of my docker images and the command for running one of them. The process just hang and doesn't send any information.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the Docker image and container identifiers used in the following examples will need to be updated with the values from your own environment.

**Run a Sitecore container based on an image:**

```
docker run -d -m 8GB --name <ContainerName> <ImageNameOrID>
```

Examples:

```
docker run -d -m 8GB -p 80 -p 443 -p8983 --name test dockerhub.io/lfaggiani/sitecore-xpsingle:9.0.2.180604-windowsservercore-ltsc2016'
```

Or

```
docker run -d -m 8GB -p 80 -p 443 -p8983 --name test 846c823a2572
```

---

**Access to the Sitecore instance that is running in the container**

You can access the Sitecore instance from your computer with your preferred browser by  following these steps:

***Get the container IP***

```
docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}} {{end}}' <ContainerNameOrId>
```

Or

```
docker exec <ContainerNameOrId> ipconfig
```

Examples:

```
docker exec test ipconfig
docker exec 5bfbd811908f ipconfig
docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}} {{end}}' test
docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}} {{end}}' 5bfbd811908f
```

***Update the local "host" file with the following entries***

```
<ContainerIP>                                   habitat.dev.local
<ContainerIP>                                   habitat_xconnect.dev.local
```

Examples:

```
172.19.118.233                                  habitat.dev.local
172.19.118.233                                  habitat_xconnect.dev.local
```

***Browse to any of the following URLs***

The first time may take some time as Sitecore has to warm up:

> https://habitat_xconnect.dev.local/
>
> http://habitat.dev.local/
>
> https://habitat.dev.local/

If no changes have been done in the build files, the domain names must be literal.

---

**Troubleshooting the container with PowerShell**

***Connect to a running container with a PowerShell console***

```
docker exec -it <ContainerNameOrId> powershell
```

Examples:

```
docker exec -it test powershell
docker exec -it 5bfbd811908f powershell
```

***Run a container with a volume that allows you to copy the Sitecore and IIS logs, and other data out of the container***

```
docker run -d -m 8GB -p 80 -p 443 -p8983 -v E:\Debug:C:\Debug --name <ContainerName> <ImageNameOrID>
```

Examples:

```
docker run -d -m 8GB -p 80 -p 443 -p8983 -v E:\Debug:C:\Debug --name test 'dockerhub.io/lfaggiani/sitecore-xpsingle:9.0.2.180604-windowsservercore-ltsc2016'
docker run -d -m 8GB -p 80 -p 443 -p8983 -v E:\Debug:C:\Debug --name test 846c823a2572
```

Once the container is running, you can connect with a PowerShell console as described above. Inside the container, anyting that is copied to the folder C:\Debug will be automatically saved in the container's host in "E:\Debug".

Comment: Thank you Ben! It's working like a charm. And thanks for the detailed information.

Comment: I've created a blog post with some additional information to help people to get started: http://bendev.es/uncategorized/get-started-with-sitecore-docker-images/

Comment: Silly question, but how can I pull an image that I have already in DockerHub but not locally?
You mention a 'dockerhub.io' URL...so I tried the same with my registry and repository, and even tried docker image pull but it's not working. I'm logged in fine as well.

Comment: The "dockerhub.io" string above is within the context of an image's name, it is not a URL.
What does "not working" mean?